# Is it possible to forbid selection in TextField?

Tags: javafx-2

I have a small problem: my text field keeps selecting itself, for example if I alt-tab from and to application.

For my application, text selection is not needed and will not be used - so I want to disallow this annoying behavior. Actually, just setting selection color to transparent or white will work fine.

Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following css fixed the problem for me:

```
-fx-highlight-fill: null;
-fx-highlight-text-fill: null;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can disable text selection for key events:

```
myTextField.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent inputevent) {
        if (!myTextField.getSelectedText().isEmpty()) {
            myTextField.deselect();
        }
    }
});
```

For mouse events you could also use:

```
myTextField.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        if (!myTextField.getSelectedText().isEmpty()) {
            myTextField.deselect();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Super late for an answer, but I have a better solution.
Instead of disabling the style for selected text or managing mouse events, it's better to directly manage the selectedTextProperty().
The advantages of this solution are:

- The selection properties will always be empty selection
- Double clicks are also covered, not only mouse drag events

The code...

```
    textField.selectedTextProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (!newValue.isEmpty()) textField.deselect();
    });
```